# what is the proper syntax of gmic apply_video

Tags: linux, image-processing, video-processing, gmic

I am trying to apply a gmic filters using `apply_video` option of `gmic` utility for linux .

```
./gmic --apply_video 'small.mp4','-denoise 30,10' -o convert.avi
```

but the output is an error in terminal

```
[gmic]-0./ Start G'MIC interpreter.
[gmic]-0./ Apply command 'small.mp4,-denoise 30,10' on video stream '', with output filename '', first frame 0, last frame -1 and frame step 1.
[gmic] *** Error in ./apply_video/*local/*substitute/ *** Command '-basename': Undefined argument '$1', in expression '$1' (for 2 arguments specified).
[gmic] Command '-basename' has the following description: 

-basename:
                    file_path,_variable_name_for_folder

    Return the basename of a file path, and opt. its folder location.
    When specified 'variable_name_for_folder' must starts by an underscore
    (global variable accessible from calling function).
```

so what is the correct syntax for gmic --apply_video ?

I am using version 1.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm using latest available version `1.7.5_pre`, and I use it like this :

```
$ gmic -w -apply_video input.avi,\"-denoise 30,10\",0,-1,1,output.avi
```

Comment: ./gmic -apply_video small.mp4,\"-denoise 30,10\",0,-1,1,small.mp4
 I tried this command and output was still some error.

[gmic]-0./ Start G'MIC interpreter.
[gmic]-0./apply_video/ *** Error *** Command '-check': Expression 'isint(-1) && -1>=0 && isint(1) && (1>=0 || 1==-1) && small.mp4>=1' is false (and no file with this name exists).

Answer (score 0):

For [G'MIC](http://gmic.eu) options, you can use the excellent offline help

```
gmic -h
```

or

```
gmic -h -apply_video
```

Which as of version 1.7.8 gives

```
    gmic: GREYC's Magic for Image Computing. 

    Version 1.7.8, Copyright (c) 2008-2016, David Tschumperle. 
    (http://gmic.eu)

-apply_video:
                    video_filename,_"command",_first_frame>=0,_last_frame={ >=0 | -1=last },
                      _frame_step>=1,_output_filename

    Apply a G'MIC command on all frames of the specified input video file, in a streamed way.
    If a display window is opened, rendered frames are displayed in it during processing.
    The output filename may have extension '.avi' (saved as a video), or any other usual image file 
      extension (saved as a sequence of images).

    Default values: 'first_frame=0', 'last_frame=-1', 'frame_step=1' and 
      'output_filename=(undefined)'.
```